# Logging bad response in nifi

Tags: apache-nifi

If i have invoked service in InvokeHTTP processor which have certain 
    response , how can i log my response, if service has bad
    response. For
    example if i have to invoke service for user id( from 1 to 5) and for
    user id=2 and it had bad response , or don't have any response

**1. how can i save previous response and then log the bad response?**

**2. Should i make this by code in ecexuteScript or i can use any native 
    nifi-proccesor?**

Answer (score 1):

There are processors for logging in nifi:

- [LogAttribute](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.3.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.LogAttribute/index.html)
- [LogMessage](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.3.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.LogMessage/index.html)

just put required as a next after InvokeHTTP processor